# Can Graph Neural Networks be better than Convolutional Neural Networks for computer vision tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing, computer-vision

Recently, a strong trend in deep learning is the adoption of Graph Neural Networks for computer vision tasks (https://github.com/thunlp/GNNPapers#computer-vision).
But the main question is could this architecture outperforms the success noted for Convolutional Neural Networks? A recent paper in bmvc2019 compared the use of GNN for object classification but the results are not clear (https://bmvc2019.org/wp-content/uploads/papers/1186-paper.pdf, the paper is explained here: https://towardsdatascience.com/can-we-do-better-than-convolutional-neural-networks-46ed90fed807 and coded here: https://github.com/bknyaz/bmvc_2019/blob/master/bmvc_2019.ipynb).
Could someone give us a clearer idea about the performance of GNN compared to CNN?

Comment: Why is this question closed? The title is pretty clear: "Can Graph Neural Networks be better than Convolutional Neural Networks for computer vision tasks?". Yes or no? If yes/no why?